# Read xml file and load its content into the array

Tags: php, simplexml

I need to read xml file and load its content into the array. What is the simplest way to do this?

```
$xml = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_file("./test.xml")), 1);
print_r $xml;
```

Comment: it would better i think to skip json_*code functions looks pointless to me

Comment: Depending on the XML it's not possible: XML is "more powerful" than simple arrays and thus you cannot map a XML directly onto such a structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try using **SimpleXMLElement** of php

```
$source = 'test.xml';

 // load as string
 $xmlstr = file_get_contents($source);
 $xmlcont = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
 foreach($xmlcont as $url) 
 {
    echo "{$url->loc} - {$url->lastmod} - {$url->changefreq} - {$url->priority}\r\n";
 }
```

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php